# Error intranlate using Flask Babel inside a looping in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to translate simple text inside a looping using flask babel. But for some reason its returning to me a

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The code:

```
{% for _ in range(1, 13) %}
    <div id="div" {% if loop.index == 1 %} class="row m-top-5" {% else %} class="row m-top-4" {% endif %}>
        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="dark-blue">
                    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
                    ,
                    {{_('começando pelo último')}}
                </p>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <hr>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-3">
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input name="date_{{ loop.index }}"
                            {% if loop.index == 1 %} onfocusout="inputMonthYear(this);" class="date-first" {% else %}
                           class="date" readonly="readonly" {% endif %} type="month" required placeholder="MM/AAAA"/>
                    <label>
                      {{_('Data')}}
                      (MM/AAAA)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-3">
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input onkeyup="k(this);" onfocusout="validateValue(this);" id="consume_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           name="consume_ponta_{{ loop.index }}" type="text"
                           placeholder=" " class="alert-status"
                           required/>
                    <label id="label_consume_ponta">
                      {{_('Consumo Ponta')}}
                      (kWh)
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="input-alert-message">
                      {{_('verifique o valor desse campo')}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-3">
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input onkeyup="k(this);"  onfocusout="validateValue(this);"  id="demand_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           name="demand_ponta_{{ loop.index }}" type="text"
                           placeholder=" " required/>
                    <label id="label_demand_ponta">
                      {{_('Demanda medida Ponta')}}
                      (kW)
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="input-alert-message">
                      {{_('verifique o valor desse campo')}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-4 m-top-4">
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input onkeyup="k(this);" onfocusout="validateValue(this);" id="consume_fora_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           name="consume_fora_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           type="text" placeholder=" " required/>
                    <label id="label_consume_fora_ponta">
                      {{_('Consumo Fora Ponta')}}
                      (kWh)
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="input-alert-message">
                      {{_('verifique o valor desse campo')}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-4 m-top-4">
            <div class="form-input" id="demand_fora_ponta">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input onkeyup="k(this);" onfocusout="validateValue(this);"  id="demand_fora_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           name="demand_fora_ponta_{{ loop.index }}"
                           type="text" placeholder=" " required/>
                    <label id="label_demand_fora_ponta">
                      {{_('Demanda medida Fora Ponta')}}
                      (kW)
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="input-alert-message">
                      {{_('verifique o valor desse campo')}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 m-top-4 m-top-4">
            <div class="form-input">
                <div class="label-float">
                    <input onkeyup="k(this);" onfocusout="validateValue(this);" id="custo_{{ loop.index }}"
                           name="custo_{{ loop.index }}" type="text" placeholder=" "
                           required/>
                    <label>
                      {{_('Valor pago no mês')}}
                      (R$)
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="input-alert-message">
                      {{_('verifique o valor desse campo')}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The error output:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/reverseproxy.py", line 23, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 28, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 66, in decorator
    return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/controllers/energy_fonts.py", line 514, in registration_cost_of_months
    group_voltages=group_voltages,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity.html", line 121, in top-level template code
    {% include 'energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html' %}
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html", line 49, in top-level template code
    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2023 08:05:48] "GET /en/fontes-de-energia/a/adicionar?font=energia-eletrica HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/reverseproxy.py", line 23, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 28, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 66, in decorator
    return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/controllers/energy_fonts.py", line 514, in registration_cost_of_months
    group_voltages=group_voltages,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity.html", line 121, in top-level template code
    {% include 'energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html' %}
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html", line 49, in top-level template code
    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 945, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 164, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1976, in do_wait_suspend
    keep_suspended = self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread, frames_tracker)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2018, in _do_wait_suspend
    if frame.f_code.co_flags & 0x80:  # CO_COROUTINE = 0x80
AttributeError: 'FCode' object has no attribute 'co_flags'
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2023 08:08:25] "GET /en/fontes-de-energia/a/adicionar?font=energia-eletrica HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/reverseproxy.py", line 23, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 28, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 66, in decorator
    return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/controllers/energy_fonts.py", line 514, in registration_cost_of_months
    group_voltages=group_voltages,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity.html", line 121, in top-level template code
    {% include 'energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html' %}
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html", line 49, in top-level template code
    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html", line 49, in top-level template code
    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 945, in trace_dispatch
    self.do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 164, in do_wait_suspend
    self._args[0].do_wait_suspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1976, in do_wait_suspend
    keep_suspended = self._do_wait_suspend(thread, frame, event, arg, suspend_type, from_this_thread, frames_tracker)
  File "/home/joao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 2018, in _do_wait_suspend
    if frame.f_code.co_flags & 0x80:  # CO_COROUTINE = 0x80
AttributeError: 'FCode' object has no attribute 'co_flags'
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2023 08:08:56] "GET /en/fontes-de-energia/a/adicionar?font=energia-eletrica HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 303, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 291, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/reverseproxy.py", line 23, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 28, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/extensions/decorators.py", line 66, in decorator
    return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/controllers/energy_fonts.py", line 514, in registration_cost_of_months
    group_voltages=group_voltages,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/joao/miniconda3/envs/brain-conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity.html", line 121, in top-level template code
    {% include 'energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html' %}
  File "/home/joao/Dev/brain/templates/energy_fonts/new-energy-fonts-eletricity-azul.html", line 49, in top-level template code
    {{_('Insira os dados dos últimos 12 meses')}}
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I can set the text outside the looping and send directly, or give the text in backend. But I want to know why this is happening...

Answer (score 0):

I find what is wrong... In the looping i'm using the character '_' as the counter and its changing the function abbreviation of gettext _ to the looping index.

```
{% for _ in range(1, 13) %}
```

The solution is using another character instead of _ on the looping

```
{% for i in range(1, 13) %}
```

or change the function abbreviation

```
{{_('<text>')}}
```

to

```
{{gettext('<text>')}}
```